# Is there any word for a "regular scale", as opposed to a "logarithmic scale"?

Tags: functions, logarithms

We all know what a "logarithmic scale" means. (It basically means that the distance between 1 and 10 is the same as the distance between 10 and 100, as shown on the figure.)

However, what is the word for the commonly used scale? Just "regular scale" or "ordinary scale", or what?

Comment: What about linear scale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linear scale is the common formulation.